# node_modules/@types/babel _template/index.d.ts :16:28 - error TS2583: Cannot find name 'Set'

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I followed [this article](https://itnext.io/step-by-step-building-and-publishing-an-npm-typescript-package-44fe7164964c) to set up a TypeScript NPM package.
The first time I ran `npm run build`(before install jest). It went really well. After that I installed `jest` and then I ran `npm run build` again, I’ve got a error message below:

> tsc
>   node_modules/@types/babel__template/index.d.ts:16:28 — error TS2583: Cannot find name ‘Set’. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to es2015 or later.
>
> 16 placeholderWhitelist?: Set;
>
> Found 1 error.

My node, npm, tsc version is: node -v // v8.12.0, npm -v // v6.4.1, tsc -v // v3.4.5

Here is tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "strict": false
  },
  "include": ["./src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/__tests__/*"]
}
```

I already excluded "node_modules" in `tsconfig.json`, how come tsc still ran node_modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)

By default all visible `@types` packages are included in your compilation. Packages in `node_modules/@types` of any enclosing folder are considered visible; specifically, that means packages within `./node_modules/@types/`, `../node_modules/@types/`, `../../node_modules/@types/`, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I did not change project anyhow (seen that in GIT changes). Just installed nodejs into Windows 10 via npm and this error message popped on me when compiling Web project of ASP.NET application (that has nothing to do with node_modules!). The only working solution that worked for me was delete and update package:

1. npm i -D @types/node
2. npm i @types/node

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the `"lib": ["es6"]` or higher and change the `"target": "es6"`  in the `compilerOptions`

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es6",
  "lib": ["es6"],
  "module": "commonjs",
  "declaration": true,
  "outDir": "./lib",
  "strict": false
}
```

Comment: I know adding ```"lib": ["es6"]``` would solve the **Cannot find name Set** problem. But I think it's babel__template's problem. They didn't provide the declaration of Set. And it's not appropriate for the application to fix this in ```tsconfig.json```. Maybe we can add a global declaration file with Set in the application and I tried, but it didn't work neither. 
could u please answer this question?
I already excluded "node_modules" in tsconfig.json, how come tsc still ran node_modules?

Comment: @BeiTang Yeah the node ecosystem is ridiculous, you suddenly add a package for testing (which is a dev dependency), and now you can't build your production code and are expected to change your `tsconfig.json`