# tsc cannot find name `Set` with jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, babeljs

I have typescript compilation setup, and compiling works perfectly.

I then install `jest` (a testing framework) as a `devDependency`. This is for development only (hence why it is a `devDependency`), and shouldn't be part of the compiled package.

Compilation now results in the following error:

```
node_modules/@types/babel__template/index.d.ts:16:28 - error TS2583: Cannot find name 'Set'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to es2015 or later.

16     placeholderWhitelist?: Set<string>;
```

- Can this error be solved, and if so, how? Adding `"lib": ["es6"]` is not am acceptable solution, as an implementation details of jest should not require me to modify my compiler options like this. Also note that `jest` runs perfectly. If there is no other solution, then that's an acceptable answer.
- Why is `tsc` compiling `devDependencies` and how do I stop this? I don't see why I should suddenly have to worry about the nested babel `devDependency` affecting my compilation.

---

Edit: `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "outDir": "./build",

        "strict": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "/src/**/?(*.)test.ts"
    ]
}
```

---

Note: This is **not** a duplicate of [node_modules/@types/babel _template/index.d.ts :16:28 - error TS2583: Cannot find name 'Set'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57055076/node-modules-types-babel-template-index-d-ts-1628-error-ts2583-cannot-fin)

This question was asking *why tsc is looking in `node_modules`* which is different from my questions (and the accepted answer is for that question).

Comment: so you've just added Jest and bundling fails? no changes made to package.json or .babelrc?

Comment: Yep, no changes. I don't have a `.babelrc`, but the error is coming from babel which presumably jest is using.

Comment: Please can you post your `tsconfig.json` ?

Answer (score 2):

> Why is tsc compiling devDependencies and how do I stop this? I don't see why I should suddenly have to worry about the nested babel devDependency affecting my compilation.

By default, `tsc` loads all the declarations in `node_modules/@types/**/*`, which in your case, includes a type declaration that depends on `>= es2015`. If that type declaration came from a `devDependency`, then `tsc` will include it. That's why `tsc` is compiling something associated with a `devDependency`.

If upgrading to `es2015` is not a valid solution, then you can also try ignoring the specific type declaration that depends on it.

From the TypeScript [documentation on @types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types):

> By default all visible “@types” packages are included in your compilation... Specify `"types": []` to disable automatic inclusion of `@types` packages.

Comment: Is there a reason why devDependencies specifically are being compiled? They are supposed to be for development and not part of the built package, right?

Comment: @DavidCallanan It isn't the `devDependencies` specifically that are a problem; rather, it is the `babel__template/index.d.ts` that is in `@types`.

Comment: This babel dependency is coming from the jest devDependency... it doesn't seem right to have to manually configure nested dependencies, they should just be hidden from me, no?

Comment: That's a reasonable request for the TypeScript team. There is an issue in the TypeScript GitHub repository about the hassle of manually configuring unwanted and possibly nested `@types` here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11917

Comment: Setting `"types": []` sounds like a reasonable solution, but now running tests using `jest`, the jest functions such as `test` and `except` are not found...

Comment: I think the best option is to have a separate `tsconfig.test.json` which extends `tsconfig.json` and adds `"types": ["jest"]`

Answer (score 1):

Considering your `tsconfig` you can:

- add `lib` to your `compilerOptions`, but you don't want impact your project because of a test lib, I understand that;
- make sure your tests use another `tsconfig`, like a `tsconfig.test.json` which have the needed `lib` => I think it's your solution;

Comment: I will try this, but `jest` runs fine with the original `tsconfig.json`, and my normal compilation `tsc` breaks. I would have expected it to be the other way around. Also making that change in a `tsconfig.test.json` still impacts my project right? Because my tests import code from my project.

Comment: Ok I see, so I think in your 'normal' `tsconfig` you may have to ignore `babel__template` types, and don't ignore it in your 'test' `tsconfig`.

Comment: Yes, but something I'd prefer to avoid. I don't see why a nested dependency of a devDependency should require me to update my production compilation.

Comment: The use of different `tsconfig` between dev and tests impact your project yes, because there is a difference of config that cause an inconsistence. The only solution I see, otherwise pass to `es6`, is to use an old version of `jest` which is fully `es5`.